# execute java program within bash script for loop using nodejs unexpected token

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, bash, for-loop

Total beginner, thanks in advance for any help. No luck in my search.

I am trying to execute a java program within a for loop. When I call the java program outside the for loop using nodejs, it works, but when I call it within the for loop I get syntax error near unexpected token nodejs. I have tried using the explicit path usr/bin/nodejs. I have used $ which nodejs to confirm the location of nodejs

in the following code example ./program executes correctly in the first call outside the loop but gives 'syntax error near unexpected token 'node'' inside the for loop.

```
# An array for the 'for' loop.

readarray list_a < ./aw_selectors_a

# Test to see if node can call ./program
node ./program

# It works.

for i in $list_a do
    node ./program

done

# It doesn't work.
```

aside: I tried to comment out my comments on this post like # but they came out bold. how do I put in the pound sign hash tag?
thanks!

Comment: Can you post your actual code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is from bash, and the problem is here:

```
for i in $list_a do
    node ./program
done
```

You need:

```
for i in $list_a; do
    node ./program
done
```

The `;` after the `for` clause before the `do` statement is crucial for `bash` to parse the script correctly.

Comment: That worked, thank you so much!

In the examples of bash for loops I've read online the semicolon ; is not mentioned. Is it because I have called an array, and are there other special circumstances where the semicolon ; is or isn't needed?

Comment: the presence of a list does not make a difference;  but, if you put the `do` on the next line, the `;` is not needed; both `;` and newline tell bash that its the end of a statement; perhaps the examples you have seen all have `do` on the next line

Comment: Ah, I see! Yes, they ... do   thanks very much for the clarification!